# Keyboard not working (ASUS VIVOBOOK S15 2022)

Tags: drivers, keyboard, asus, budgie

I just installed Ubuntu Budgie 22.04 on my new ASUS Vivobook OLED S15 S3502 (2022). The keyboard is not working while the touchpad is working. But the external keyboard is working fine.

My grub entry;
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

How can I make it work fine?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue with s14 vivobook, Did you find any solution for the above issue?
there is one more ticket with similar issue https://askubuntu.com/questions/1419702/vivibook-s14-oled-s3402-keyboard-not-detected
Please update you found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The official fix for Asus Vivobook 2022 models will be rolled out with kernel 6.1 releases - [ [ref1](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=216158) ], [ [ref2](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=216579) ]

For an immediate fix try these solutions,

[Vivibook S14 OLED (S3402) keyboard not detected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1419702/vivibook-s14-oled-s3402-keyboard-not-detected?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Correct way to build kernel with hardware support fix patches - Ubuntu 22.04 LTS - 5.15.0-50](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1435591/correct-way-to-build-kernel-with-hardware-support-fix-patches-ubuntu-22-04-lts?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Issues With Dual Booting of Asus Vivobook/Zenbook series laptops with Ubuntu 22.04 (S14, Filp 13, pro 14, pro 15 etc)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1432177/issues-with-dual-booting-of-asus-vivobook-zenbook-series-laptops-with-ubuntu-22?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: I think the fixes are now added to latest Ubuntu kernel releases, I am using Ubuntu 22.10 with kernel version 5.19.0.28.29 and the Keyboard issue now resolved,