# Vivibook S14 OLED (S3402) keyboard not detected

Tags: kernel, keyboard, kubuntu, asus

I recently got the VivoBook S 14 OLED (S3402,12th Gen Intel i7) and tried installing Kubuntu (22.04) on it. However, the onboard keyboard does not work after grub stage. I managed an install with an external USB keyboard but need to solve this soon.

I have looked at various solutions including adding "i8042.reset i8042.nomux i8042.nopnp i8042.noloop" to linux boot parameters into grub. Nothing seems to help. The touchpad works but the keyboard does not. In the live session for 20.04, even the touchpad does not work.

The issue is the same with the current daily build of 22.10 which also uses the 5.15 kernel.

Comment: Ubuntu 22.10 doesn't yet exist; it's currently the *development* release Ubuntu *kinetic* and remains that until it reaches RC state which isn't expected until after 13 October 2022, and isn't on-topic here until release on 20 October 2022.  https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/kinetic-kudu-release-schedule/27263  Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic.  For support issues with Ubuntu *kinetic* you'll need to use a #ubuntu-next or #ubuntu+1 site (IRC, UF etc)

Comment: Then please consider Kubuntu 22.04. 22.10 was only mentioned in the context of various attempts to a solution.

Comment: I'd have put it in brackets or tried at least to reduce it's inclusion as you've made it rather prominent. You also mention *focal* or 20.04, but gave no useful specifics as to which ISO/kernel stack you tried; ie. did you try GA or 5.4 which is very different to 22.04? HWE 5.8/5.11/5.13/5.15 or which?  You're missing what could be useful details about 20.04 (*22.04 is still new & has few options currently*) but seem to highlight off-topic *kinetic*.

Comment: I can check and confirm the kernel but i tried the standard release 20.04.2 which is the iso i had. I can see that there is now 20.04.04 which i am going to try next. For completeness, kubuntu 21.10 failed to boot.

Comment: FYI:  20.04.2 ISO used the 5.8 kernel stack from Ubuntu 20.10; 20.04.4 will use the 5.13 kernel stack from 21.10 (*thus I'd assume same results as your Kubuntu 21.10 trial... whilst the kernel & thus kernel modules [aka drivers] will be the same, 20.04 uses the much older LTS Qt5 & KF5 stack + much older KDE too which I'd not expect to make any difference; the kernel stack is where I'd look which is why the ISO used matters at least to me*)

Comment: Yes, the kernel matters and was not aware of the kernel changes between dot releases of 20.04. I noticed that kernel 5.19.0 has just been introduced into proposed repo of 22.10. Tried downloading and installing in the 22.04 installation. It fails to boot and falls to the initramfs terminal.

Comment: Just fyi, but you can read https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack for details of the HWE kernel stack option; LTS releases offer GA (no change; default for servers) & HWE (using later stacks from non-LTS releases; default for Ubuntu Desktop from 20.04 & later, also default if 20.04.2 or later media is used for *flavors* like Kubuntu, but 20.04 & 20.04.1 used GA stack by default with *flavors*).  Some boxes also have OEM kernel stack options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### I faced the same issue with Asus Vivobook s 15 and compiled kernel 5.19.5 with patch provided here https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=216158 and it worked for me too.

I've uploaded the same to https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1_29NPWOjJ_RGy9Oh-SnSdgEPBBVfEJHt?usp=sharing and you can download all 4 deb files and install them and boot to kernel '5.19.5 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Aug 29 16:57:23 IST 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux' and it should work for you too.

In case you want to build your kernel, let me show the straightforward steps.

1. Install mainline package  `sudo apt install -y mainline` and install tools for compiling
   `sudo apt install -y build-essential libssl-dev libncurses5-dev gcc bc bison flex libelf-dev`
2. search for the mainline app and install the kernel you want to build as it will give the correct kernel config when we will build the kernel. Reboot the laptop to boot into this kernel.
3. Eg. you have installed 5.19.5 then go to kernel.org and download the same version(it's better to match the versions)
4. Create a new dir and move the kernel tar there. eg.

`mkdir mykernel`
and
`cd mykernel`
and place the linux-x.xx.x here.

5. `mkdir linux_kernel`
6. `tar xvf linux-* -C linux_kernel/ --strip-components=1`
7. `cd linux_kernel`
8. `cp /boot/config-$(uname -r) ./.config`
9. patch the kernel for the against using below
   https://bugzilla.kernel.org/attachment.cgi?id=301690
   the issue below command to patch the src.

   `patch -p1 < ~/Downloads/fix-irq-vivobook.patch`
10. `sudo make deb-pkg`
11. You might face issues for Debian certs. To fix that do below.
    `sudo apt install -y linux-source`
    and copy the certs from

    `cp -v /usr/src/linux-source-5.15.0/debian/*.pem debian/`
12. Again start the build process.
    `sudo make deb-pkg`

    this may take 1 to 2 hours so please wait.

If all is well then you'll get the kernel build in parent dir.

13. `cd ..`
14. `sudo dpkg -i *deb`
15. Verify grub config and reboot and you'll get a working keyboard.

Clean up: open mainline > remove the version you installed in step 2.

Comment here if you face any issues and I'll try to help. :)

Indeed I'm typing for Vivobook's Keyboard only. All thanks to the amazing Linux community. :)

Comment: Found this answer because my ASUS Vivobook S 14X OLED S5402Z has the same problem. So I modified the patch to match for "S5402ZA" (got the value from dmidecode), but unfortunately it doesn't help :( Perhaps someone has an idea?

Comment: Noted that the given 5.19.5 kernel patch has some issues like display refresh rate cannot be changed (no 60Hz option), high battery usage - on Ubuntu 22.04 - model Asus Vivobook s14-k3402za.
Tried to build from mainline kernel as mentioned, but the built deb package got several issues, finally settled with applying patch to Ubuntu source kernel that solves refresh rate and thereby battery drain to some extend, mentioned in answer
https://askubuntu.com/a/1435592/1172766
Happy to remind that the fix will be added with kernel release 6.1

Comment: @BusinessTomcat Follow thread for S5602ZA-  https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=216579 - the fix will be added with kernel release 6.1

Comment: I think the fixes are now added to latest Ubuntu kernel releases, I am using Ubuntu 22.10 with kernel version 5.19.0.28.29 and the Keyboard issue now resolved,

Answer (score 1):

I found a patch for this issue here https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=216158, however, I not very familiar with applying patch to kernel.

Comment: @KishoreJonnalagadda DO NOT share personal email here or ask for off-site support here.  This is forbidden by the rules of the site, and is a good way to open yourself up to phishing attacks.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the exact same issue on my Vivobook S 14x OLED. As mentioned in https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=216158, upgrading the kernel to 6.1-rc1 or above would perfectly solve this problem.

[Mainline Linux kernel from Ubuntu](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/?C=N;O=D)

[How to Install the Latest Mainline Linux Kernel Version in Ubuntu](https://itsfoss.com/upgrade-linux-kernel-ubuntu/)