# Issues With Dual Booting of Asus Vivobook/Zenbook series laptops with Ubuntu 22.04 (S14, Filp 13, pro 14, pro 15 etc)

Tags: dual-boot, keyboard, display, asus, fingerprint-reader

I’ve encountered several problems (on my own & found over internet) with dual booting of latest LTS Ubuntu 22.04 along with windows 11 for Asus laptop models (using Asus Vivobook S14 S3402ZA)

version: Ubuntu 22.04.1 with kernel 5.15.7

Problems encountered

1. Not Showing USB boot option (directly goes to windows as default)
2. Storage not detecting (when trying to install)
3. Keyboard not detecting but external keyboard working (issue/bug reported with some of latest vivobook/zenbook models)
4. Cannot get in to dual booted after Ubuntu install - (asking encryption key)
5. Fingerprint scanner not detecting and occasional lags and stuck with UI on Ubuntu (especially with browser)
6. Is there any better options for battery saving like reducing refresh rate (showing fixed 90Hz) for Ubuntu.

Can someone provide instructions for new/intermediate users to install and use Ubuntu/linux distributions on these laptop models.

***Edit***: Posted as a self answered question, found solutions for mentioned issues 1 - 4 and 6 which are added in the answer but needed solution for fingerprint scanner detection(if available), tried some solutions but not worked.

Comment: The picture does nothing for the question other then forcing anyone looking at it to have to scroll down.

Comment: @David image just added to indicate the type of models I'm specifying in the question, removed it too as I've also found it gives no values, thanks for pointing that too.

I must add that every questions are not for pros, its just added in absolute beginners space, for me it just took a lot of time just to properly install ubuntu on one of these machine, this question just meant to help newcomers to install ubuntu and probably save some of their time,
Apart from the instant demotivation, any kind help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Possibly more info: ASUS ROG Strix G15 Linux 5.13 stable series or Linux 5.14 req'd. Newer Software components the better. AMD
https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=asus-g15-distros&num=1 & Asus Zenbook UX425EA w/Intel Iris Xe Graphics - turn off optane with Windows Optane app
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2458373
Someone posted this: After setting the fast boot option to Auto, it worked! ASUS TUF GAMING FX506L - Install nVidia driver
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2460560

Comment: @oldfred Thanks for the suggestions, before installing the custom kernel mentioned in the answer which is 5.19 (patched with keyboard fix), the fresh installation was on 5.15 - that has unsupported keyboard issue - not tried the latest 5.19.11 without patch, setting the fast boot option and secure boot option worked for me too and I've added that in the answer, the question also updated accordingly. As the kernel releases include more hardware support, hoping the issue will fix soon and will also update that here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Answering to my own question,

**TLDR**
: The solution to particular problems mentioned in question are numbered along with the steps)

Complete Step-by-Step procedure that worked for me to dual boot Ubuntu 22.04 along with Windows 11 on my Laptop (Asus Vivobook S14 S3402ZA) - key specs

- Intel i5 12th gen
- Iris Xe graphics, with oled 90hz display

#### Dual boot Ubuntu

- Download the ISO file from official [Ubuntu website](https://ubuntu.com/).
- On windows do a `win+r` → `msinfo32` to get BIOS mode information, check that it is `UEFI`.
- Requisites for install- windows 11 or 10 system, 8 GB or higher pendrive, 50+ GB Harddrive
- Download [rufus tool](https://rufus.ie/en/) to flash ISO to pendrive.
- Search for “Disc Management” in windows and find the main partition, Also check the disc partition type `MBR` or `GPT` , from right clicking any partition → properties → volume, (For `UEFI` BIOS the partition will be `GPT`).
- Right click the partition, `shrink volume`, here we are adding a space of 140 GB for Ubuntu from available.

  [image: Disc partition windows]
- Insert the pendrive, backup if any files present in it, if it is already a bootable clean it using `diskpart`

  ```bash
  # on windows cmd open diskpart
  diskpart

  # list disks
  list disk

  # find the disk here it is disc 1 (sandisk USB), select your disk
  select disk 1

  # verify disk
  detail disk

  # perform cleaning
  clean

  # create primary partition (try repeat if failing)
  create partition primary

  # Activate the partition
  active

  # Finally format back to ntfs/fat32 as required (here fat32)
  format fs=fat32 quick
  format fs=ntfs quick
  ```
- Open rufus as administrator,  choose the following options , base boot image, Also choose the recommended “ISO Image mode” for writing after clicking start.

  [image: rufus settings ubuntu 22.04]
- Turn off windows Bitlocker encryption for Harddrive - as in the following step we are going to disable secure boot, windows will ask to manually enter the [encryption key](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/finding-your-bitlocker-recovery-key-in-windows-6b71ad27-0b89-ea08-f143-056f5ab347d6) the next time you log on. So consider [turning off the storage encryption](https://www.howtogeek.com/805225/disable-bitlocker/) in `settings` →`Usage & Security`, [**Solves the problem 4**]
- BIOS settings that need to changed, (for asus BIOS panel press `F2` while Turning on after asus logo appears) (To hard power off - press the power button key for 15 seconds - you may need it), video for [asus boot](https://youtu.be/BKVShiMUePc).

  1. [Fast Boot](https://www.asus.com/us/support/FAQ/1044641/) (Turn off fast boot) - [ **Solves problem 1**]
  2. [Secure Boot](https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1042711/) (Disable Secure Boot) - [ **Solves problem 2**]
  3. Change the boot order to make the USB one first on BIOS Home page. [**Solves Problem 1**]
- Now a GRUB window will open up with “Try or Install Ubuntu” option, click and it will first do some file checks.
- Before installing Ubuntu 22.04, just try it out for checking any hardware incompatibility - (Here encountered a major problem for my laptop - the keyboard is not working with Ubuntu - only external keyboard working - [**Problem 3**])
- Opt to install Ubuntu, use an external keyboard - will fix the internal keyboard problem later,

  Created partitions from already allocated SSD free space,

  1. ROOT PARTITION - `/` -  85 GB
  2. Home partition - `/home` - 52 GB
  3. `SWAP` - rest of the size (around 8 GB ~ half of RAM Size) - not mandatory as there is enough RAM.

  No need to create a separate `efi` partition as efi partition for windows already exists, `ubuntu` grub will be installed and loaded from it.
- Now choose the other options and install Ubuntu, click restart, pull out pendrive and press enter.
- Deal with Keyboard Issue - Downloaded the kernel files that listed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1419702/vivibook-s14-oled-s3402-keyboard-not-detected) (with live patch applied - pre-built- v 5.19.5), move all to a single location and install them with

  ```bash
  sudo dpkg -i *.deb
  ```

  Or you can apply patch and build your own kernel with the steps mentioned here -

  [Vivibook S14 OLED (S3402) keyboard not detected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1419702/vivibook-s14-oled-s3402-keyboard-not-detected)
  Thanks @amitdalal for the excellent answer.

  [ **Solves the problem 3** - see the below step too]
- [**Update** - ***read this if you got time for compiling***, Also the official fix will be available in **kernel version 6.1**]

  Noted that with the pre-built-custom-patch kernel 5.19.5 from the above step got some issues that the display refresh rate cannot be adjusted and high battery usage even with power saver mode.

  Tried custom building from new version of mainline kernel from kernel.org that introduces some new issues [Stated Here](https://askubuntu.com/q/1435591/1172766).

  Finally settled with patching incoming source Ubuntu kernel that gives 60Hz support and better battery life.

  Follow these steps to do that - https://askubuntu.com/a/1435592/1172766

  [**Solves Problem 6**]
- **Problem 5** still unresolved,

  It shows the fingerprint reader hardware with `lsusb` and tried to update the fingerprint library with,

  ```bash
  sudo apt install fprintd libfprint-2-2
  ```

  But the fingerprint option not showing in `Settings -> Users`,

  Decreasing the screen timeout, using system-wide dark mode, will help reduce power usage, using `tlp` will also help.

Comment: Where to install grub in advanced mode installation? Would it be like default hard disk (sda)? or would it be a specific partition (efi or /) ?