# Ubuntu support in Asus Vivobook S14

Tags: drivers, asus

I have ordered an Asus Vivobook S14 S3402ZA and am waiting for the delivery. I just wanted to know if there are any major problems after installing Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. I found [some of the fixable issues here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1432177/issues-with-dual-booting-of-asus-vivobook-zenbook-series-laptops-with-ubuntu-22#1432567).

Some of my doubts are:

- the display burn-in problem. The laptop comes with Windows pre-installed and has features to delay screen burn-in. Will I have something similar in Ubuntu?
- are all the physical ports recognizable in Ubuntu, such as the two thunderbolt 4 ports? and
- all in all, performance-wise, is this laptop a good deal for use as an Ubuntu daily driver machine? My previous laptop was a Dell so I haven't faced any major Ubuntu-related issues. If there is any major concern I would cancel the delivery.

Comment: I suggest you boot from the Ubuntu installation USB and use the **Try Ubuntu** option. This option does not change anything in your computer's internal drive, and runs Ubuntu directly from the USB. You will be able to answer all your questions by trying Ubuntu. Computer manufacturers often change internal components even with the same product numbers. Therefore, even if you find someone with the exact make and model of your computer running Ubuntu, there is no guarantee your experience will be the same as theirs.

Comment: I'm using the same model laptop with Ubuntu 22.04 as my daily driver, no issues apart from no fingerprint reader in user settings, a keyboard not working issue may show up which is linked in my answer - https://askubuntu.com/a/1432178/1172766
After that, no issues with touchpad gestures, all valid function keys working, 
I would suggest you to try out latest kernel available and check that will it fixes the keyboard issue, screen burn will only be an issue for 30+ above minutes high brightness static images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take it point by point:

### Laptop Burn-in Problem

Ubuntu comes with a pre-installed screensaver (it's just black). You can control the timeout in "settings". You can also install other third-party screensavers that are a bit more exciting.

### Thunderbolt 4 Support

Since Linux Kernel 5.8 ([see reference here](https://www.techradar.com/news/linux-58-released-features-thunderbolt-40-support-and-improved-security)), Thunderbolt 4 has been fully supported. Ubuntu Jammy Jellyfish (22.04) comes with kernel version 5.15, so that is all covered. Anecdotally, I have a HP laptop with 22.04, and Thunderbolt 4 works fine.

### Performance

Ubuntu uses a lot less CPU and RAM than Windows (reference = anecdotal evidence, and [this now-deleted Reddit question](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/9t189p/from_windows_10_to_ubuntu_way_lower_cpu_usage/)), so if you think that PC is suitable for a Windows Daily Driver, it will do even better on Ubuntu.

I also just looked at the Asus website, and here are two reasons why it will suit you as a daily driver:

- Intel 12th Gen CPUs have a cool dual-core architecture that brings lots of performance; and
- Your computer has an SSD, which is fast.