# Unable to boot ubuntu, or anything, from USB

Tags: boot, networking

Completely new to Linux and am wanting to try out Ubuntu from a USB. When attempting to boot I am receiving an error message which I've attached below. I also decided to try out other linux distributions and all seem to have the same problem. I'm currently unable to get anything to boot. Selecting the "Ubuntu (safe graphics)" option seems to work, however it isn't detecting my WiFi network.

Ubuntu version: 22.04.2 LTS

Hardware: Asus Vivobook k6604 - Intel 13980hx cpu - Nvidia rtx 4070 gpu

Any help is appreciated.

[image: Error message]

Edit: I was able to successfully boot Ubuntu version 23.04 though I'm still getting "No Wi-Fi adapter found"

Comment: That is a very new CPU. You may do better with 23.04 to have newer kernel & drivers. We normally suggest the LTS versions with 5 year life, but very new systems often need latest drivers. You will need Safe Graphics with nVidia, and need to choose to install restricted drivers to install the correct nVidia driver. You may need to change some UEFI settings, but not familiar with that model. 12 gen answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1432177/issues-with-dual-booting-of-asus-vivobook-zenbook-series-laptops-with-ubuntu-22

Comment: It's always TOUGH luck with latest hardware. I have latest hardware and I had to find and install drivers for WiFi and Bluetooth manually. And I have to do it every time there is a Kernel update. So, your problem is pretty much the same. You need to research a bit about your hardware and if compatible drivers are available or not for Linux starting with the WiFi model first... (use Windows' Device Manager to get the Hardware info)