# Ubuntu install does not see disk

Tags: system-installation

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 22.04 on a ASUS vivoPC.  I have copied the ISO to a flash drive using Rufus.  When I load in the ISO i get to the 'Guided storage configuration' part of the install and I get this message, 'Block probing did not discover any disk. Unfortunately this means that installation will not be possible.'. Can some one tell me what is happening and how to correct the problem. I only have one disk installed.

Comment: Probably, Windows "Fast Boot" left the disk in a confusing state. Boot your install medium in "Try Ubuntu" mode, and read `man gparted`.

Comment: May also be Windows bitlocker. Or drive setting in UEFI. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1432177/issues-with-dual-booting-of-asus-vivobook-zenbook-series-laptops-with-ubuntu-22