# Which OS type should I set in Asus UEFI BIOS utility?

Tags: uefi, bios, settings

I want to install Ubuntu. The utility shows two options: Windows UEFI mode and Other OS. Respective info text says: Configure system as UEFI/Legacy mode.

Comment: What utility? Why are you in the BIOS at all? What are you doing there? And since the only two options are "Windows" and "other", isn't "other" the obvious choice?

Comment: That may really be UEFI Secure Boot or just UEFI. My older motherboard said if installing Windows 7 (now obsolete) use "Other" as Windows 7 did not support UEFI Secure boot. With Secure Boot off, you then may have option for UEFI or CSM/legacy/BIOS boot mode. CSM - UEFI Compatibility Support Module (CSM), which emulates a BIOS mode, only available with secure boot off. Do not use BIOS mode. How you boot install media UEFI or BIOS is then how it installs.

Comment: Your question is specific to your *unstated* hardware of which you gave no details. If the Ubuntu ISO is written correctly (*as documented*) it will install on Secure-uEFI, uEFI or BIOS (legacy/CSM) modes without change on almost all hardware (*though reformat options on ISO write can prevent this; so best to just clone ISO to flash/USB/media as QA tested*).

Comment: @terdon the utility I get when I press delete or F2 when system boots. I wonder, if the setting matters.

Comment: OK, that's the EFI setup menu, but why are you going there at all? What setting do you want to change and why?

Comment: @oldfred I do not notice any change in other settings depending on the setting. Could it be that my system does not have UEFI secure boot option? How do you choose in which mode you boot install media?

Comment: If you have UEFI, you just about have to have UEFI Secure boot. Microsoft required UEFI/gpt with Secure Boot starting in 2012 and release of Windows 8. So almost all systems are UEFI. Only  a few tablet type systems may be different. Some like Acer require control S, many require setting an UEFI password. If you set password never forget it, or reset back to blank or later you may have major issues. What model Asus? Do you have latest UEFI firmware from Asus? UEFI boot menu should show two options for Ubuntu live installer. One clearly UEFI and one not, if you made UEFI installer.

Comment: @oldfred VivoPC with latest firnware

Comment: Are you trying to install Ubuntu alongside Windows as a dual boot?

Comment: Some perhap similar Asus: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1432177/issues-with-dual-booting-of-asus-vivobook-zenbook-series-laptops-with-ubuntu-22 & Asus Vivobook reinstall correct nVidia driver for geforce rtx 3050 mobile gpu
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2475408 & https://askubuntu.com/questions/1162452/problem-installing-ubuntu-in-a-laptop-with-intel-optane Do you have Optane and nVidia in your model?

Comment: @karel no, ubuntu only, possibly as a media server for my local network.

Comment: @oldfred no, only integrated Intel graphics, does it matter? I don't know about Optane.

Comment: Intel only should make it a bit easier. Optane is an now obsolete technology from Intel as small SSD used only for Windows hibernation as Windows boots so slow. Many remove Optane module & add NVMe drive, but if you have it, you must change to AHCI, not RAID or Intel RST in drive settings in UEFI. Check UEFI setting on drives.

Comment: @oldfred I didn't find anything about Optane or NVMe in UEFI settings. The PC has a PCI Express and a Mini PCI Express, but how do you know, if they can be used for mass storage? Is that somehow relevant when you choose the OS type in UEFI settings?

Comment: Never used PCI Express, but should not make any difference on OS type.

Answer (score 0):

Select the following options in the UEFI setup utility:

Boot mode: UEFI
  Secure Boot: <sup>*</sup>Disabled
  Boot order: Put the Ubuntu live USB first in the boot order.

<sup>*</sup>It is possible that the Ubuntu installer may be unable to correctly install the Ubuntu bootloader in Secure Boot mode on some computers due to hardware incompatibility.

Comment: Oh, but isn't it worth trying the secure boot?

Comment: Ubuntu sometimes works normally with Secure Boot enabled in the UEFI setup utility. If Ubuntu does not boot with Secure Boot enabled in the UEFI setup utility then enter the UEFI at boot time and disable it. I don't think that there is much to lose by trying it on a newly installed Ubuntu.