# Error while lauching Ubuntu installed over Windows 10

Tags: boot, 22.04, windows-10, bios

Installed Ubuntu 22.04 and replaced it with Windows 10. While launching it, it shows some error, but after a few seconds it launches properly. Why am I getting this issue?

[image]

```
[   0.416305] tpn_crb NSF10101:00: [Firmware Bug]: ACPI region does not cover the entire command/response buffer. [mem Oxdd470000-Oxdd470fff flags 0x2001 vs dd
[   0.416922] tpn_crb MSFT0101:00: [Firmware Bug]: ACPI region does not cover the entire command/response buffer. mem Oxdd474000-Oxdd470fff flags 0x2001 vs dd
```

Comment: Have you updated UEFI & SSD, to latest firmware available from vendor? May be similar issues: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1432177/issues-with-dual-booting-of-asus-vivobook-zenbook-series-laptops-with-ubuntu-22  What graphics does your system have?