How to install Ubuntu on an Asus Vivobook pro 15 K6502V?
I just bought the laptop in the title. It comes with an intel core i5 processor and nvidia graphics card. When I boot from ubuntu image (USB), the computer enters the ubuntu trial and I can use ubuntu except for the unrecognized NIC and a popup window telling about 'system error' (I can get over the details later since I'm not in front of the computer as I write this). I wonder if there's a solution for my laptop or if this sort of Vivobook is incompatible with Ubuntu. Also, the installation prompt won't go past the point where you select the installation type (advanced or basic). I'd appreciate it if anyone who has managed to install ubuntu on the same or similar laptop model can give me some guidance.

This question is similar to: How do I install Ubuntu?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You provided no specifics as to what Ubuntu product, nor release of that unstated product of Ubuntu you are trying to install. Ubuntu comes in various products, that use different installers and you've not said what you tried. There is also some kernel stack choice; which is important because what are commonly called drivers are kernel modules; thus change if you change kernel stack, with different ISOs using different stacks. Being specific with Ubuntu details may help us to help you. Also be aware this is a Q&A site (not a forum) so the question should be specific to a problem.

You mention 'system error' but give no clues as to what checks you made or if you performed any on the ISO or write of ISO to media; as these take seconds and I see them as cheap insurance as they save hours-days of diagnostics if problems are encountered as you mention; you also didn't mention if you explored system logs etc on your unstated Ubuntu product/release. Did you follow the tutorials for your chosen Ubuntu product/release?

If you have nVidia, you need to boot with safe graphics & install restricted extras to get drivers. You may need to resolve Internet issues, but that is search by vendor chip as even similar models may have different chips. Older https://askubuntu.com/questions/1432177/issues-with-dual-booting-of-asus-vivobook-zenbook-series-laptops-with-ubuntu-22 Not familar with ufs drive, but one model needed this: ASUS Vivobook go 15 e1504ga  needs ufshcd_pci for ufs drive
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2499206

This question is similar to: Bootable USB of Ubuntu Minimal CD. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
