Why does Ubuntu fail to install to a external device every time?
I am trying to install Ubuntu to an SSD in an enclosure. I followed every step and always get an unknown error. I went to \var\crash and there is a crash file with 17K lines of stuff. IDK what to do... I have tried so many times... If this helps at all I am using an Asus Vivobook 14.

I have installed just about every release, but use Kubuntu on all my drives. Bit lighter weight for external use also. Often lighter weight flavor better for external use as USB port can be bottleneck unless very new system. Light weight flavors:
Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Budgie
Flavors of Ubuntu only come with three years of supported life (five years applies to Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server but not flavors) But I also gpt partition in advance and put ESP - efi system partition as first partition for UEFI boot. and boot installer in UEFI mode. Specify external drive's ESP as efi.

@oldfred I am new to Linux and that stuff in general.. I don't understand much of that... sorry

Are you installing Ubuntu or one of the lighter lavors? Using manual install or one of the auto install options which I refuse to use as I really do not know what they are doing. They usually work ok for very standard configurations total erase drive or dual boot on internal drive. Post this in question from terminal in live installer. sudo parted -l Asus Vivobook S14 Also Zenbook
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1432177/issues-with-dual-booting-of-asus-vivobook-zenbook-series-laptops-with-ubuntu-22

@oldfred I am  installing Ubuntu desktop. Also I can get it to try to install. the error only occurs during the installation.

UEFI install & do you have gpt partitioning & an ESP on drive? Some fail is ESP - efi system partition not found and may not let you create it during install depending on install method.
