# Correct way to build kernel with hardware support fix patches - Ubuntu 22.04 LTS - 5.15.0-50

Tags: kernel, keyboard, 22.04, asus, patch

**Main Question**:

Need a solution to apply a hardware support patch to my current working kernel in Ubuntu 22.04, so that it will fix the exact issue (here keyboard not working) without affecting other settings.

***Background***

Tried dual booting Ubuntu on my laptop(Asus vivobook s14-K3402ZA), the installation succeeded but keyboard was not working from boot, later found that only external keyboard is supporting and internal keyboard not working with Ubuntu `22.04 LTS` - kernel `5.15.0-50-generic`

The issue was identified at “Try before install” and do proceed because I found a patch [online that solved the issue for similar models](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=216158) - from the information got from comments It will be added in a future 6.1 kernel release.

But in order to get it working on current mainline kernel, Tried the steps mentioned in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1426342/1172766).

Downloaded latest longterm 5.15 release `5.15.74`, Successfully complied the `.deb` package and installed - the keyboard issue fixed but there are several other issues regarding display brightness, scaling, refresh rate etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the issue is because the Ubuntu / Debian release kernel comes with some extra patches or may be due to the configuration difference in installed kernel version and the one from [kernel.org.](https://www.kernel.org/)

Note that  `5.15.74` is a mainline Linux version and mentioned `5.15.0-50` is an Ubuntu version, both are not same.

As all other functionalities are working in source kernel, it is better to build a custom patched kernel from source kernel to correct the issue.

Steps to follow,

1. Enable source code repositories, this will add needed deb-src lines in `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

   [image: enable-source-repo]
2. Install the tools require to compile the packages from source code,also ensure around 20+ GB disc space before building.

   ```bash
   # To install build tools
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt build-dep linux linux-image-$(uname -r)

   sudo apt install libncurses-dev gawk flex bison openssl libssl-dev dkms libelf-dev libudev-dev libpci-dev libiberty-dev autoconf llvm build-essential libncurses5-dev gcc bc dwarves
   ```
3. Obtaining the source for Ubuntu release: The source code which generated a specific binary package may be obtained using the `apt source <package>` command, to get other versions check this - [official documentation](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel), [ [ref-2](https://kernel-team.pages.debian.net/kernel-handbook/ch-common-tasks.html#s-common-official) ]

   ```bash
   # switch to root
   sudo su

   # get the current kernel source downloaded and extracted (ignore the end user warning)
   apt source linux-image-unsigned-$(uname -r)

   cd /path/to/linux-<version>/

   # Give all user execution permissions to scripts (Important, otherwise error will be thrown even if you are running them as root)
   chmod a+x debian/scripts/*
   chmod a+x -R ./scripts
   ```
4. Download and apply the patch,

   ```bash
   patch -p1 < ~/Downloads/<patch-name>.patch
   ```
5. Copy the existing configurations,

   ```bash
   cp /boot/config-$(uname -r) ./.config

   # update config for new kernel
   make oldconfig
   ```
6. Compile the kernel, [[ref](https://passthroughpo.st/patch-kernel-debian/)]

   ```bash
   make -j16 deb-pkg LOCALVERSION=-custom
   ```

   You want to replace `-j16` with however many threads your processor has (use `getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN` to get the number). the `“LOCALVERSION”` option can be anything you want. It’s only there for documentation purposes. Now your kernel should be compiling. This could take a while, depending on your hardware (1-2 hours)
7. Install the new patched kernel, update grub and reboot to new kernel

   ```bash
   # change to parent dir
   cd ..

   dpkg -i *.deb

   update-grub
   reboot
   ```

   Use the mainline tool to remove old kernel,

Answer (score -1):

Tried using the mainline tool to install the latest (already fixed and patched) kernel?

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cappelikan/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mainline


And then use the tool.
```

Comment: Not only a bad answer an extremely bad idea. Using an untested test kernel will interfere with upgrades.

Comment: Coul,d you not install only LTS or stable kernels with that? Am I wrong?